Does wave function collapse create an infinitely small point of infinite density?
In the standard model of particle physics elementary particles act as a wave function until observed at which point the wave function collapses to a singular point. When this particle is observed and it is narrowed to a 0 dimensional point does this create an infinitely small point of infinitely high density? Also does the infinite density not
being created until observation have an impact on the behavior of these particles, how  would it be different if this weren't the case?

The standard model is built on Quantum Field Theory (QFT), where there are no wavefunctions. There are fields and eventually (depending on the formalism chosen) wave-functionals.

"Wave function" is often used to just refer to the quantum state, and there are quantum states in QFT.

@Travis There is a difference between being right, and abusing the language.

I think it's justified to call the quantum state the wave function because you can always decompose it into energy modes which evolve according to a wave equation.

The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle (HUP) states that
$$\sigma_x\sigma_p\ge\frac{\hbar}{2}$$
for positional and momentum uncertainties $\sigma$, respectively. To collapse the wave function to a single point in the way I think you’re describing, you would need to perform an observation that would produce a positional uncertainty of exactly $0$.
This violates the HUP. Essentially, what you can do is check if the particle is in a given region of space, but not if it’s at a particular point; observing the particle’s position in the former way produces nonzero positional uncertainty, any value of which corresponds to a possible value of momentum uncertainty that does not violate the HUP.

This would happen if the particle collapsed to an eigenstate of the position operator. These states get a lot of attention. Any state can be constructed from a sum of them. But collapse to a point does not happen.
A typical example would be an electron encounters a positive ion and collapses to a bound state. The state is an orbital.
Another example is a photon in an approximate monochromatic plane wave state passes through a pinhole. A true monochromatic plane wave, an eigenstate of the momentum operator, would exist for all time and fill all space. We don't speak of interaction or collapse unless the photon hits the screen instead of the pinhole. Perhaps we should. The state immediately after passing through the pinhole is just big enough to fill the pinhole.

What exactly happens when the wave function collapses depends on the specific interpretation of quantum mechanics.  There is no mainstream interpretation that says that it collapses down to an infinitely small point under any circumstances (even though it's useful to make that approximation when doing calculations).  In GRW theory, the wave function collapses at random down to a Gaussian centered around certain particles.  In Bohmian mechanics, the universal wave function never collapses, but the wave functions of subsystems collapse in accordance with how those subsystems are interacting with their environment, and it is impossible for the environment to be such that you would ever get an infinitely dense collapse.
